# There exists an odd function such that $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx \neq 0$

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck on this problem for a long time. I'm very grateful if some one can help me solve this.Thanks.

> > Suppose $f$ is an odd non-zero continous function, prove that there exists another odd function $g$ such that $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x)dx \neq 0$.

Thanks

Comment: If $f$ is odd, $f^2$ is even.

Comment: Huh, you means in that case, $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)^{2}dx = 2 \int_{0}^{1}f(x)^{2}dx \ge 0$. But how can we reject the equal mark???

Comment: $f\neq 0\implies f^2>0\implies \int_{-1}^1 f^2(x)dx>0$

Comment: Well, if $f$ is continuous and non-zero in at least one point in $[-1,1]$, then $f^2$ is positive therefore $\int_0^1f(x)^2dx$ is greater than zero.

Comment: $g = f$ works if $f$ is not 0 :) Otherwise $g$ doesn't exist.

Comment: As two answers say, $f(x)=0$ is odd and you can't reject equality in that case.  It is also true if $f(x)=\begin {cases} -1&x=-0.5\\1&x=0.5\\0&otherwise \end {cases}$.

Comment: To reject equality to zero, you need to insist $\int_{-1}^1 |f(x)|dx \gt 0$

Comment: "$f\neq 0 \Longrightarrow f^2>0$" is false. $f^2$ could perfectly be zero in some (if not most) points.

Comment: @imj: good point, so I think it's not enough information to conclude if we take $g = f$

Comment: If $f$ is non-zero and continuous, the integral of $f^2 > 0$ and $g = f$ should work.

Comment: @Macavity: I think in your case, you just conclude that the interal $\ge$ 0, not $>$ 0

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, then $f^2$ is continuous.  But if $f(p) = c \neq 0$ for some point $p \in [-1, 1]$, then $f^2(p) = c^2 > 0$ and by continuity, there is a neighbourhood $[p - \epsilon, p+\epsilon]$, where $f^2(x)$ must be arbitrarily close to $f^2(p) = c^2$. This would make the integral positive. Hence $f$  non-zero and continuous imply a positive integral for $f^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

doesn't work for $f=0$ :/

If $\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx\neq 0$, then $g=f$ works.

Comment: Yes, I guess he should add the hypothesis that f is non-zero somewhere and integrable...

Comment: @GustavoMarra:  it needs more than that.  You can change a few points of $f$, leaving it integral but the integral is still zero.

Comment: Yes, I saw your example up above. I guess the hypothesis that needs to be added is taht $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Take $g(x) = f(x)$. Then you have
$$
\int_{-1}^1 f(x)^2\; dx = 2\int_0^1 f(x)^2\; dx.\;
$$
The only way this can be zero is if $f(x) = 0$ (for all $x \in (0,1))$ because $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$. Note here that $f(x)^2$ is an even function because $f(-x)^2 = (-f(x))^2 = f(x)^2$.

Comment: "The only way this can be zero is if f(x)=0." You need continuity for that.

Comment: $f(x)=1$ if $x=0.2$  $f(x)=-1$ if $x=-0.2$ otherwise f=0, is a clear counter example.

Comment: @imj: It is continuous!

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: I wrote that the only way that this can be zero is if $f(x) =0$....

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: Note that we have the integral of $f(x)^2$ not just $f(x)$.

Comment: Sorry, didn't note continuity.

Comment: @IshanBanerjee: No problem